# Can't Install libsodium for PHP 7.1 on CentOS 7

Tags: centos, php

I installed the package `php71-php-pecl-libsodium` and then added `extension=libsodium.so` to my `php.ini` but when I run `php -i | grep sodium` I get:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/libsodium.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/libsodium.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

I do have a `/usr/lib64/libsodium.so` and a `/usr/local/lib/libsodium.so`. I tried to link the first one to the expected path for PHP but when I do that, it says it's not a valid PHP extension. How can I install this?

If I try to install the pecl version, I get:

```
Error: Package: php-pecl-libsodium-1.0.7-1.el7.remi.5.4.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: php(zend-abi) = 20100525-64
           Installed: php-common-7.1.11-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php71)
               php(zend-abi) = 20160303-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-42.el7.x86_64 (base)
               php(zend-abi) = 20100525-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-43.el7_4.x86_64 (updates)
               php(zend-abi) = 20100525-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.45-13.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               php(zend-abi) = 20100525-64
```

also tried compiling from these instructions but still no .so file in the proper location, even after `make install`: https://paragonie.com/book/pecl-libsodium/read/00-intro.md#installing-libsodium

CentOS 7

PHP 7.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have installed php 7.1 from "remi-php71", you need php-pecl-sodium from the same repository.

See the [Wizard](https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/) instructions to permanently enable the needed repostiory.

```
yum-config-manager --enable remi-php71
```

Notice, you have the choice between 2 packages

- **php-pecl-libsodium** which provides v1 API (deprecated)
- **php-pecl-libsodium2** which provides v2 API, same as in upcoming PHP 7.2